# If condition not working with CodeIgniter validation

Tags: codeigniter, validation, if-statement

I'm using CodeIgniter! I have 3 radio buttons - to choose role. If you choose one of the three radio buttons, you see different dropdowns. I want to make validation rules - to echo validation errors only on these dropdowns for the radio button you have chosen. I tried with this but it doesn't show me any validation errors. 
First, my radio buttons are:

```html
 <input type="radio"   name="role_id[]" onClick='showHide(this, true)' id="radio1"  value="1" />
 

   $data=array(
    'name' => 'role_id[]',
    'value' => '2', 
    'id' => 'radio2',
    'onclick' => 'showHide(this, true)'
    );
  echo form_radio($data);

  $data=array(
    'name' => 'role_id[]',
    'value' => '5',
    'id' => 'radio5',
 'onclick' => 'teachers_show(this, true)'
    );
  echo form_radio($data);
```

My controller is:

```html
 public function register()
    {
      ​
 if ($this->input->post('role_id[]') === 1){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', First name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'trim|required'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|is_unique[users.username]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Confirm password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');  
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('school[]', 'School', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('class[]', 'Class', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('role_id[]', 'Role', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('class_divisions[]', 'Class division', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('region', 'Region', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('teacher[]', 'teacher', 'required');
        
        }
     ​
 elseif ($this->input->post('role_id[]') === 2){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', First name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'trim|required'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|is_unique[users.username]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Confirm password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');  
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('school[]', 'School', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('class[]', 'Class', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('role_id[]', 'Role', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('class_divisions[]', 'Class division', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('region', 'Region', 'required');
      
        
        }
         elseif ($this->input->post('role_id[]') === 5 ){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('all_teachers_show', 'ALL Teachers', 'required');

        }
        if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {
            $this->signup();
        }
        else 
        {  ​
//register
}
}
```

If I use something like this:

```html
  if ($this->input->post('role_id[]') < 2){​
           // validation rules
     }
    
   if ($this->input->post('role_id[]') >4 ){​
           // validation rules
     }
```

It shows me validation errors but for role_id=1. For role_id=5 shows me validation errors that are for role_id=1.
Could you help me? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing string `'value' => '2'` and trying to compare if [identical](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `===` to integer `2` which evaluate to `FALSE`. [Cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) your input to specified integer and see what have you got after. I.e. `(int)$this->input->post('role_id[]') === 2`.

```
public function radiobutton()
{
    echo form_open('test/passingthrough');
    echo '<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1" ' . set_radio('myradio', '1', TRUE) . ' />';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2" ' . set_radio('myradio', '2') . ' />';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="5" ' . set_radio('myradio', '5') . ' />';
    echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Radio button!');
}

public function passingthrough()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mysubmit', '', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('myradio', '', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        redirect('test/radiobutton', 'refresh');
    } else {
        echo '<pre>', var_dump($this->input->post('myradio'));
    }
}
```

In this example passed value (and since it is radio, there will be one passed value for sure) will be something you are looking for. But also, if I get you right, you need NULL, FALSE or what ever value for non passed values. So you would have array of all values in your action controller or model, and check it in foreach loop for it:

```
$possible_values = array(1, 2, 5);
foreach ($possible_values as $p_v) {
    if ($this->input->post('role_id') == $p_v) {
        //do what do you want with TRUE 'role_id'
    } else {
        //do what do you want with FALSE 'role_id'
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried with:  if ($this->input->post('role_id') == 2){ but no errors show. My radio buttosn are named 'role_id[]' and they have values of 1, 2 and 5.

Comment: In that case `==` you are checking if equal wich doesn't compare data type. If [is_identical](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.is-identical.php) or `===` checks data type (string, integer, boolean...).

Comment: How to check if role_id[] is 1, 2 or 5?

Comment: I've just edited my answer to let you see how to pass radio button value. Detailed explanation you can find in [docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html). 
Now, I am looking at your code again and seems like you are making indexed array with `$role_id[]`. It starts with zero index so you have different expectations, maybe. If first value is clicked it is `$role_id[0]` not `$role_id[1]`.

Comment: Radio buttons have values- $data=array(
    'name' => 'role_id[]',
    'value' => '2', 
    'id' => 'radio2',
    'onclick' => 'showHide(this, true)'
    );
  echo form_radio($data);
If I write if ($this->input->post('role_id') == 2){ why it is wrong? I have set value 2 of radio button.

Comment: You don't need square brackets in name. Use just role_id for name of input fields. And use same name for all input fields.

Comment: Yes, it works, but another problem. I changed radio in my view to be role_id, and validation works, but in my model I have:  
            foreach ($this->input->post('role_id') as $value)
            {$data = array('role_id' => $value 
                    ); $this->db->insert('users', $data) - it doesn't insert in users role_id, how to correct it?

Comment: Edited answer. Check it.

Comment: Thank you, i't's great now! I'm used to write if ($this->input->post) I haven't written in with this array. Thanks  ;)

Comment: Np. Glad was helpful.